# How to express dwell time in G-code

Tags: g-code

I am writing some G-code for my DIY 3D printer. From what I understand, `G4` is dwell and its expressed in milliseconds. So my extruder takes about 30 seconds to heat up. Do I just type

```
G04 30000
```

Comment: This question suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Mick's answer accurately addresses the titular question, while Larry's actually gives the best solution for your problem? Is there any reason you need to do the waiting based on a fixed period of time (e.g., because your extruder does not have closed-loop temperature feedback)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about needing to specify the dwell value in milliseconds. However, the RepRap Wiki indicates that you need to use the `Pn` argument, and not just an unadorned number as the argument to the command. To adapt the Wiki's own example, you will need to use:

```
G4 P30000
```

This should cause the firmware to dwell (pause) for 30 seconds.

[RepRap Wiki: G4: Dwell](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G4:_Dwell)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your G-code flavor you may be able to use [`M109`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M109:_Set_Extruder_Temperature_and_Wait) (heat and wait) instead. If supported M109 will wait until the target temperature is achieved.